# Is it necessary to set rbl_viewController when using Rebel's RBLViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, github-for-mac

As the title states, I've been wiring up the rbl_viewController outlet in my XIBs, however on a closer read of the RBLViewController API, this property does seem to get set automatically.

Is it necessary to set rbl_viewController when using Rebel's RBLViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't! rbl_viewController is assigned within RBLViewController's -setView: method.